# Vimeo Embedded Code is not Working in Android 4

Tags: android, html, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I had embedded a vimeo code in to my Webpage, here i had a problem in viewing that video in Android ver.4  and above Tablets. But in Samsung 2.2 and in Kindle Devise  it is working perfectly Can any one Help me in Over come this Problem..........